# How do I disable the top hand-grab feature in Windows 8.1 - update 1 (after Spring)?

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui-snapping

This is the last annoyance I cannot disable.
I boot to desktop, use Classic Shell, removed hot corners.
But this feature is the last I cannot seem to remove.

Which feature I mean exactly?
The one that lets you snap your whole (entire) desktop to one side of your screen.

How do I disable this thing?

Comment: **Both answers on the other question are not working on a fresh Windows 8.1 update 1 - with Spring update.** In fact, I can grab the desktop even easier than before. ;_;

Comment: Doesn't make it a different question.  If you would like newer/updated answers on the existing question please [consider placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing one. With 10K+ in rep, you've got plenty to spare. ;)